# How to add item to object with array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object which has an array of other objects and I want to add new objects to that array.

```
const linkData = {
      data: [
        {
          linkName:
            "Link Name.",
          linkAddress:
            "https://whatever.com",
        }]
```

I tried doing:

```
linkData.data.push({ 

 linkName: "New Link Name.",
 linkAddress: "https://newAddress.com",

})
```

But it adds only one object to the array and doesn't append any next object I pass to it.

Comment: You're only calling `push()` once, so it only appends one object to the array.

Comment: You can use `push()` to add as many objects in the `data` array.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code your linkdata is a constant variable. so first you have to change const to var like below.

```
 var linkData = {
          data: [
            {
              linkName:
                "Link Name.",
              linkAddress:
                "https://whatever.com",
            }]

var newData = [...linkData.data, {
              linkName:
                "Link Name1.",
              linkAddress:
                "https://whatever1.com",
            }]

linkData.data = newData;
console.log("linkData.data = ",linkData.data);
```

Comment: `const` is fine in this case, because the code isn't reassigning `linkData` in either the original code or in your example. No need to change it to `var`.